# VarChar to Int Limit Value MS Access

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to pull the number of times certain numbers are dialed on specific dates. However, despite adding a Cast in on my Dialed_Num column from a varchar to an int, I still get the error that 'the conversion of varchar value overflowed an int column'   Is there a way to limit the varchar value I pull? I thought I would anyway, because I only want the two numbers pulled that I specified in my Where Clause

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate date = '2018-09-01', @EndDate date = '2018-09-05'

SELECT

CAST (SEGSTART as Date) as LocalDay,
CAST(Dialed_Num as INT) as DIALEDMODNUM

FROM
oauser.cmsCallHistory cms

WHERE SEGSTART BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate AND [Dialed_Num] IN(6582000,6752000);
```

Comment: Why do you tag "ms-access"? What kind of SQL are you using? Please apply appropriate tags only, to avoid incorrect answers and get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Is your previous question on the "CallHistory" topic obsolete?

Comment: @JennaTerral . . . You have tagged the question MS Access, but the code is not MS Access code.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dialed_Num` column need to `cast`, which is in `where` clause.

```
SELECT
   CAST (SEGSTART as Date) as LocalDay,
   CAST(Dialed_Num as INT) as DIALEDMODNUM
FROM oauser.cmsCallHistory cms
WHERE 
   SEGSTART BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate 
AND 
   CAST(Dialed_Num as INT) IN(6582000,6752000);
```